# Шанс на рандомные числа

Tags: случайные-числа

Каков шанс того, что одно рандомное число от 1 до 10 будет равно другому рандомному числу от 1 до 10?

Comment: Если числа целые и распределение равномерное, то 1/10. Если вещественные - то 0.

Comment: Ну только не ноль, а стремление к нулю :)

Comment: А сколько всего таких рандомных чисел?

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, что генератор чисел "честный" и вероятность выпасть для каждого числа одинаковая. Тогда:

- шанс, что выпадет какое-то конкретное число: `1/10`
- шанс, что выпадут подряд два одинаковых таких числа: `1/10 * 1/10`
- поскольку нам всё-равно, какое именно число выпадет, то вариантов конкретного числа у нас `10`

Перемножаем это всё: `1/10 * 1/10 * 10 = 1/10`

Проверим на всякий случай с помощью Питона на выборке из `100 000` пар случайных чисел:

```py
import random

n = 100_000
print(sum(random.randint(1, 10) == random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(n)) / n)
```

Вывод:

```
0.09964
```

ГСЧ у любого языка программирования не совсем идеальный, но получилось вполне близко к `1/10` или `0.1`.

Или даже так. Сделаем серию экспериментов - `100` экспериментов по `100 000` пар случайных чисел и посмотрим у них среднее и стандартное отклонение:

```py
import numpy as np

k = 100
n = 100_000
tests = (np.random.randint(1, 11, (n,k)) == np.random.randint(1, 11, (n,k))).mean(axis=0)
print(f'{tests.mean():0.3f}±{tests.std():0.3f}')
```

Ну, тут ещё точнее получается:

```
0.100±0.001
```